# Windows System Image taking way to much space

Tags: windows-7, backup

Im using Windows Backup to take backups of my system to a network location. Because of this, windows tells me that because im saving to a network location, only the most recent system image will be retained. But this System Image takes up allmost 1TB of space on my network location!

Why is this, and how can i fix it?

Here is a screenshot:

[image: http://peecee.dk/uploads/122014/Sk%C3%A6rmbillede_2014-12-11_23.26.39.png]

Comment: How many backups are there? What size is your system drive?

Comment: System drive is 100 GB, and there is only one backup it seems (one backup period listed)

Comment: @DanielJørgensen Check the retention policy of the backup. If you are having more restore points, it will consume more space

Comment: @vembutech - Where can i do this ? If you mean the settings for the system image, as you can see in my screenshot, windows tells me, that i cannot change those settings because i save the backup to a network location.